# How can I use variable created inside of pipeline (from gradle.properties file) within an template as a task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an java project which have gradle.properties file. Im extracting variables defined in gradle.properties as

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVariable;]`my script to extract it from gradle.properties`
```

Then im using template from another repository that needs that variable but I can't use it within task, but when I try use it within `- script: echo $variable` as a step instead of task it is working.
When i try to use it within task it sees variable as $variable not a value.

Maybe there is a better way to extract variables to azure pipeline instead of using this approach?

Comment: Hi, You can print the variable but cannot use it in the task, right? you could feel free to share your pipeline definition here, we could check it and locate the issue. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Yes, you are right - just uploaded my code below, it is not the same as previously, because I have refactored it meanwhile but the idea is the same

Comment: Hi @Yoza, This is by design, check my answer, if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi @Yoza, If this answer is helpful, would you please accept it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the error message:

[image: This is by design]

We get the error before the pipeline run the **bash** task, Since it cannot create the variable `parampass`, we get the parameters value is  $(parampass) instead of the variable value.

Check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax):

- In a pipeline, template expression variables `${{ variables.var }}` get processed at compile time, **before runtime starts**. Macro syntax variables `$(var)` get processed **during runtime before a task runs**. Runtime expressions `$[variables.var]` also get processed during **runtime** but were designed for use with conditions and expressions.

As a workaround:

pipeline.yml

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-20.04

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: common
    type: git
    name: organisation/repo-name

variables:
  - name: parampass
    value: xxx

stages:
- stage: "Build"
  jobs:
  - job: "Build"
    steps:
    - template: templatename.yml@common
      parameters:
        par1: ${{ variables.parampass}}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do not provide variable to your template

Example execution of template with provided parameter

```
- template: my/path/to/myTemplate.yml@MyAnotherRepositoryResourceName
  parameters:
    projectsToBeTested: $(someVariable)
```

And example template accepting parameters

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Just testing'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: ${{ parameters.projectsToBeTested}}
```

Please provide more information if it does not help.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but it doesn't matter if im providing variable by parameters or not, it still sees it as $(variable)

Comment: Can you provide your code or screenshoots?

Answer (score 0):

Code looks like this:

pipeline.yml

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-20.04

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: common
    type: git
    name: organisation/repo-name

stages:
- stage: "Build"
  jobs:
  - job: "Build"
    steps:
    - bash: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=parampass]anything"
    - template: templatename.yml@common
      parameters:
        par1: $(parampass)
```

templatename.yml

```
parameters:
- name: par1

steps:
- task: SonarCloudPrepare@1
  displayName: SonarCloud analysis prepare
  inputs:
    SonarCloud: ${{ parameters.par1}}
    organization: 'orgname'
    scannerMode: 'Other'
    extraProperties: |
      # Additional properties that will be passed to the scanner,
      # Put one key=value per line, example:
      # sonar.exclusions=**/*.bin
      sonar.projectKey= # same param pass case
      sonar.projectName= # same param pass case
```

Generally, it does not matter if i do have parameters passed or  if I'm using the template as if it were part of the pipeline code within. Output is always $(parampass) could not be found or smth